# How to return partial view from inside the HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
 public static PartialViewResult DateTime(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {


             return System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 
        }
```

and now I want to return a Partial view from inside the DateTime method. But helper instance does not have any method for partial view.

UPDATE 2:

I think a better question to ask is that how can I return the HTML of the Partial View from inside the HtmlHelper (custom)

Comment: A partial view is of type PartialViewResult... what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to create an extension method which can be used to return a shared view for multiple projects.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to create a helper that returns a string and not an actual view.   That's fine (and makes much more sense than a helper which returns a partialview), just make these little tweaks:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DateTime(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   return MvcHtmlString.Create( System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this breaks the MVC pattern a bit. You want a `Controller` that is responsible for a `View`. I would create a controller that has an `Action` that returns your `View`.

If you don't want to be able to do anything else than using it as a partial view, there are attributes for that. This way you stick to the MVC pattern and you can use the extension `@Html.RenderPartial`.

Your example of returning a `DateTime` is possible to solve as @Robert Levy said, but if you really want to try and return a `View` from outside a `Controller` I would strongly advice against trying that.